# WPF performance issue when trying to update listbox real-time based on user input

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone-7.1

I'm new in Windows Phone development and i'm trying to develop a dictionary app.
I have a textbox to allow user input the word and a listbox to show all words which match the user input in real-time, so I'm used the textchanged event as below:

```
private void searchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            wordNeedToDefine = searchTextBox.Text;
            if (!(wordNeedToDefine == null || wordNeedToDefine.Equals("")))
            {
                var items = (from words in wordAndIndexList where words[0].StartsWith(wordNeedToDefine) select words[0]);                    
            }
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                wordsListBox.ItemsSource = items;
            });
    }
```

Everything is working fine but there are issues about performance, it's laggy when user input the text and listbox update the items.
Can someone tell me what i need to do to increase the performance. I'm also trying the AutoCompleteBox but it's have same problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many items are you loading into the ListBox?

Comment: Another thing to consider to, is using a timer -- in a real use case, a user might type 'hi', and wait a second hoping to see 'hippo'. You could set a timer in text changed, and reset it every press. after 2/3 second, you could then change the itemssource. Might be a case of too 'real-time'

Comment: @PaulDiston: items depend on how many words that math the user-input (up to 800). But i think it is not problem since althought i have 1 item, it still laggy.

Comment: @willmel: i have tried your solution before, it's works well. But what i want is the true real-time. I have see it works smoothly in other's dictionary app, so it's can be done. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll get better performance if you use a [`CollectionViewSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to do the filtering and the more characters you have to filter will make it faster. i.e. Only start filtering once the user has entered at least 3 characters.